# java - how to create and manipulate a bit array with length of 10 million bits

Tags: java, bitmap

I just came across a problem; it was easy to solve in pseudo code, but when I started coding it in java; I started to realize I didn't know where to start...

Here is what I need to do:

1. I need a bit array of size 10 million (bits) (let's call it A).
2. I need to be able to set the elements in this array to 1 or 0 (A[99000]=1).
3. I need to iterate through the 10 million elements.

Comment: You should look into the `BitSet` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: this should be the answer, and the only acceptable one.

Comment: Thanks Hunter McMillen!

Comment: How would you guys recommend to set a bit array of 1000000000000000 ? For the life of me, I can seem to find out!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) (as Hunter McMillen already pointed out in a comment). You can easily [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get%28int%29) and [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int,%20boolean%29) bits. To iterate just use a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 32):

The "proper" way in Java is to use the already-existing BitSet class pointed out by Hunter McMillen.  If you're figuring out how a large bit-array is managed purely for the purpose of thinking through an interesting problem, then calculating the position of a bit in an array of bytes is just basic modular arithmetic.

```
public class BitArray {

    private static final int ALL_ONES = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int WORD_SIZE = 32;
    private int bits[] = null;

    public BitArray(int size) {
        bits = new int[size / WORD_SIZE + (size % WORD_SIZE == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
    }

    public boolean getBit(int pos) {
        return (bits[pos / WORD_SIZE] & (1 << (pos % WORD_SIZE))) != 0;
    }

    public void setBit(int pos, boolean b) {
        int word = bits[pos / WORD_SIZE];
        int posBit = 1 << (pos % WORD_SIZE);
        if (b) {
            word |= posBit;
        } else {
            word &= (ALL_ONES - posBit);
        }
        bits[pos / WORD_SIZE] = word;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I had to change it a little because what I'm doing is little-endian

Comment: @Midnightas, how did you have to change it? Java itself is endian-agnostic.  The array stores the least significant int first, which is already the little-endian way.  But overall, the class is designed such that the ordering is abstracted away from the user anyway.

Comment: (Also, while it's good to learn from this example, you should probably just use `BitSet` in real life for more speed/robustness.)

Comment: @mwfearnley It was reading bits in this order: 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,etc...

Comment: @mwfearnley And BitSet didn't have some features that I needed.

Comment: But Java doesn't have a concept of bit (or byte) ordering.  That has to be a separate order that you've defined somehow.  I'm going to hazard a guess that you're wanting to use this as a kind of bit stream (e.g. with Huffman coding)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more optimized implementation of *phatfingers* 'BitArray'

```
class BitArray {

    private static final int MASK = 63;
    private final long len;
    private long bits[] = null;

    public BitArray(long size) {
        if ((((size-1)>>6) + 1) > 2147483647) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Field size to large, max size = 137438953408");
        }else if (size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Field size to small, min size = 1");
        }
        len = size;
        bits = new long[(int) (((size-1)>>6) + 1)];
    }

    public boolean getBit(long pos) {
        return (bits[(int)(pos>>6)] & (1L << (pos&MASK))) != 0;
    }

    public void setBit(long pos, boolean b) {
        if (getBit(pos) != b) { bits[(int)(pos>>6)] ^= (1L << (pos&MASK)); }
    }

    public long getLength() {
        return len;
    }
}
```

Since we use fields of 64 we extend the maximum size to 137438953408-bits which is roughly what fits in 16GB of ram. Additionally we use masks and bit shifts instead of division and modulo operations the reducing the computation time. The improvement is quite substantial.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] A = new byte[10000000];
A[99000] = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

If you really want bits, you can use boolean and let true = 1, and false = 0.

```
boolean[] A = new boolean[10000000];
//etc
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This uses 80 million bits. So 10 million bytes.

Comment: hmmm - a question the size of a boolean is one bit?

Comment: boolean values are manipulated as 32-bit entities, but arrays of booleans use 1 byte per element.